# Xamarin iOS WkWebView and WebRTC microphone not work in background

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I´m using `WkWebView` in `Xamarin` for `iOS` to show a webapp WebRTC based. My app uses WebRTC to call other app and I´m using only audio. The app works perfectly, but:

First problem I´m facing is when the app goes to background, outcoming audio (iPhone microphone) is muted, but incoming audio still continues working. App does not disconnect and the webview does not freeze, only microphone is muted.

I have noticed something different when open my app in Safari: the iOS status bar changes its color and shows that microphone is being used, while when in my app (using WkWebView) this not happens. Also, Safari not mutes the microphone in background.

Am I forgetting something in WkWebView config?

[image]

Comment: Could you check if you have added the permission for [microphone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/infoplist-reference#microphone) in info.plist ?

Comment: Yes, I have added the NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key in Info.plist

Answer (score 2):

We reproduced this issue in native Apple and tried to add UIBackgroundModes "audio" and "voip" in info.plist to see if they make a difference.

Unfortunately, they did not. So this is an Apple / WebKit issue. We found a thread on Apple's forum talking about the same issue with a webRTC app in WKWebView: [WKWebView getUserMedia microphone … | Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/689182).

Also, there is a WebKit bug report as well: [233419 – WKWebView microphone access not working in background (webkit.org)](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=233419). So please follow up with them.